# What determines the "speed" of current-tech motherboards? [2021]

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard, speed, fsb

Back a decade or so, I built my PC while in Uni and the basic limiting factor for a motherboard's internal communication was the Front Side Bus speed. Too low a frequency (i.e. data transfer rate) in the build could cause bottlenecking. Back then, the one I picked(Think it was a ROG Maximus Extreme) had a 3200 MHz FSB speed, if I remember correctly(Big IF). (I bought a gaming MB because it seemed like the best for the price)

Now I'm looking to build a Gaming PC for my nephew (and maybe one for myself...) but, as I'd expected, things have changed quite a bit. The basic physical layout of the boards look the same, but I can't find a FSB speed or another speed to compare different boards.

So...
Could you please explain the current speed limiting factor in modern MBs so I can make a more informed choice. Also, do they still have a Northbridge and Southbridge-type layout? If You think anything else is relevant to my problem, I'd like to hear that too.

> **My Research**
> I've checked Wiki but they just talk about the old designs really, they don't say in a summary way what's going on in modern MBs. Other websites talk about FSB as if it's still relevant.
> [Northbridge (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northbridge_(computing))
> [FSB (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front-side_bus)

Comment: The speed limit on very modern structures is "how close together" the components are - monolithic CPUs with built-in RAM & GPU are blowing the competition out of the water right now. Starting with 'a mobo' plus 'a CPU' plus 'a GPU' plus 'RAM' & you're already waaay behind the curve.

Comment: PCIe slot speed may be a consideration. Essentially, if you're using a discrete graphics card, you'll want to have a board with at least one 16x speed slot and use that to connect the card. The tradeoff is that the remaining slots will likely be slower speed (e.g. 4x or 8x), assuming you might want to add additional hardware, such as SSD add-on cards. This [article](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.tomshardware.com/amp/reviews/pcie-definition,5754.html) arguably has a decent overview of PCIe slot basics.

Comment: The FSB article in no way claims to be relevant now, the first sentence of the Wikipedia article literally says "often used in Intel-chip-based computers during the 1990s and 2000s" so it hasn't really be relevant for a while. The modern equivalent of the Northbridge is the [Platform Controller Hub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Controller_Hub)

Comment: I totally agree with @harrymc s answer. Today, unless you don't know a lot about the different components, you risk choosing a sub-optimal configuration which will make you spend more than on a OEM PC for the same performance. But if you want to go on, start googling for "pc building guide 2021" or similar. Take yourself a month of time for research, then choose your components.

Comment: oh and dont forget to google for "best gaming motherboard" and "best gaming cpu", as well as "amd vs intel" ...

Comment: @Mokubai Hi! I didn't mean Wikipedia articles claim FSB is still relevant, others I looked at do. I think they were old pages so I left them out of the research links.

Answer (score 2):

Things are much more complicated now. Performance is dependent on the total
system throughput, where the slowest component counts.

Building a PC has also now requires much more knowledge and errors are
easy to come by. It's more economical in many cases to buy a good
ready-made computer, rather than build one yourself.

The best source for comparison of computer components is
[PassMark](https://www.passmark.com/),
where you will find all these benchmarks:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer harrymc. The first line is the same as ever I think, a data-processing system is always limited by the slowest component. Thats why you took note of the FSB as it was usually the limiting factor on a system. I would have liked a bit more detail on how it's changed. But thanks you gave me some things to think about.